# how to extract first two characters from an array in html using angular?

Tags: angular

I have a api array object returning value as below:

```
apival = [{lang: "English",code: "en-ca"}, {lang: "French",code: "fr-ca"}]
```

I am using this array with ngfor to display the languages in the html. I need to specify a condition to apply some logic. For that, I need a pipe or something which extracts first two characters from the code in runtime.

I know how to split this in typescript. But, I need it in HTML.
In my TS:

```
currentlang = "en"
```

In my HTML:

```
<div*ngfor="let x of apival">
<div*ngIf="x.code == currentlang"></div>
</div>
```

In the above html code, I need a way to extract the first two characters from the code. Any idea how can I do this?

***I dont want to use TS, I can use a pipe or some logic in html***

Comment: In HTML, have you tried `x.code.substring(0, 2)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using a `Pipe` it's the correct way. Try this:

```
@Pipe({ name: "code" })
export class LangCodePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any[], filter?: string): any {
    return value
      .map(lang => {
        return {
          ...lang,
          short: lang.code.split("-")[0]
        };
      })
      .filter(lang => {
        return filter ? filter == lang.short : true;
      });
  }
}
```

It will contain the logic that you need and also makes the filter optional, the `Pipe` returns the actual object but also the short code.

Now all you need to do is: declare the pipe in your module and use it in your template.

```html
<!--currentLang is optional param-->
<div *ngFor="let x of apival | code: currentlang">
  {{x | json}}
</div>
<!-- you can also do this -->
<div *ngFor="let x of apival | code">
  {{x | json}}
</div>
```

[Full example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-langcode?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: great!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I used @Oscar Ludick way. Using a pipe is ideal way. I am just posting this if anyone needs an extra option.

```
x.code.split('-')[0] === currentLang
```